# Symfony2.3 - HWIOAuthBundle Config ServiceNotFoundException

Tags: php, symfony, bundle, config, hwioauthbundle

I want to install this bundle. I follow all of the steps and I have this error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException' with message 'You have requested a non-existent service "hwi_oauth.resource_ownermap.main".' in /home/Project/app/bootstrap.php.cache:1894
```

Anyone has an idea ?

Comment: This is too succinct. We need more things here such as your conf etc etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution here :
http://www.diegocaprioli.com/adding-hwioauthbundle-to-your-symfony2-project/

You need to configure a ressource_owners in config.yml

Comment: The oauth/resource_owners section of the firewall in security.yml is required to correct this error.