# HWIOAuthBundle & FOSUserBundle integration

Tags: php, symfony, oauth, fosuserbundle, hwioauthbundle

I followed these two documentations :
https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/tree/master/Resources/doc (for HWIOAuth)
https://gist.github.com/danvbe/4476697 (to integrate HWIOAuth with FOSUB)

And I get this error

> ServiceNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent service "hwi_oauth.resource_ownermap.main".

I found the same error in stackoverflow :
[Symfony2.3 - HWIOAuthBundle Config ServiceNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17488959/symfony2-3-hwioauthbundle-config-servicenotfoundexception)

But I think that my ressource_owners in config.yml is well configured.

Here is it :

```
 fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: MyProject\UserBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
        form:
            type: myproject_user_registration
        confirmation:
            enabled: true
            template: FOSUserBundle:Registration:email.txt.twig



 hwi_oauth:
    firewall_name: main
    fosub:
        username_iterations: 30
        properties:
            yahoo: yahoo_id
            google: google_id
            windows_live: windows_live_id
            linkedin: linkedin_id
    resource_owners:
        any_name:
            type:                yahoo
            client_id:           X
            client_secret:       X
        any_name:
            type:                google
            client_id:           X
            client_secret:       X
            scope:               X 
        any_name:
            type:                windows_live
            client_id:           X
            client_secret:       X           
        any_name:
            type:                linkedin
            client_id:           X
            client_secret:       X
            scope:               X
```

I have the right values instead of X (without any "" I don't know if I should add this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `resources_owners` section of the firewall in security.yml must also be configured to avoid that error.

```
firewalls:
    main:
        oauth:
            resource_owners:
                facebook:           "/login/check-facebook"
                twitter:            "/login/check-google"
```

Comment: Thanks the problem was that I had secured_area instead of main.

Answer (score 1):

Also did you include your bundle `services.yml` in the main config file?

```
 #/app/config/config.yml

 imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: "@UserBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }
```

Answer (score 1):

My error was that I had

```
    secured_area:
         oauth:
             resource_owners:
                 facebook:           "/login/check-facebook"
                 twitter:            "/login/check-google"
```

instead of

```
    main:
         oauth:
             resource_owners:
                 facebook:           "/login/check-facebook"
                 twitter:            "/login/check-google"
```

in the file security.yml

Thanks.